VBA Macro to mail merge a word doc to pdf in bulk - adjustment to code
We have a macro that we currently use with an excel file to mail merge large volumes to word documents and pdfs.
The code works really well but we actually only need to generate pdfs not word documents (for which the code does both).
Is there a way / how could we adjust the code below so that it only produces pdfs and not word documents?
The fact it produces word documents is fine but as we have so many records to merge to pdf I was wondering if removing the merge to word documents would speed up the merge process. Currently it takes around 1/2 hour to merge 500 (to both word and pdf).
Sub MailMergeToPdfBasic()                                                        ' Mark the start of the Subroutine (i.e. Macro) and name it "MailMergeToPdf"
' Macro created by Imnoss Ltd
' Please share freely while retaining attribution
' Last Updated 2021-05-03
    Dim masterDoc As Document, singleDoc As Document, lastRecordNum As Long   ' Create variables ("Post-it Notes") for later use
    Set masterDoc = ActiveDocument                                               ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc when Macro run) as "masterDoc"

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord                   ' jump to the last active record (active = ticked in edit recipients)
    lastRecordNum = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord                  ' retrieve the record number of the last active record so we know when to stop

    masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord                  ' jump to the first active record (active = ticked in edit recipients)
    Do While lastRecordNum > 0                                                   ' create a loop, lastRecordNum is used to end the loop by setting to zero (see below)
        masterDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument                    ' Identify that we are creating a word docx (and no e.g. an email)
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord              ' Limit the selection to just one document by setting the start ...
        masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord               ' ... and end points to the active record
        masterDoc.MailMerge.Execute False                                        ' run the MailMerge based on the above settings (i.e. for one record)
        Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument                                           ' Identify the ActiveDocument (foremost doc after running the MailMerge) as "singleDoc"
        singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
            FileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("DocFileName").Value & ".docx", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument                                      ' Save "singleDoc" as a word docx with the details provided in the DocFolderPath and DocFileName fields in the MailMerge data
        singleDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            OutputFileName:=masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFolderPath").Value & Application.PathSeparator & _
                masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("PdfFileName").Value & ".pdf", _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF                                      ' Export "singleDoc" as a PDF with the details provided in the PdfFolderPath and PdfFileName fields in the MailMerge data
        singleDoc.Close False                                                    ' Close "singleDoc", the variable "singleDoc" can now be used for the next record when created
        If masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord >= lastRecordNum Then     ' test if we have just created a document for the last record
            lastRecordNum = 0                                                    ' if so we set lastRecordNum to zero to indicate that the loop should end
        Else
            masterDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord           ' otherwise go to the next active record
        End If

    Loop                                                                         ' loop back to the Do start
End Sub                                                                          ' Mark the end of the Subroutine


You could comment out the singleDoc.SaveAs2 if you don't need the Word versions.  Not sure if that would speed things up by much though.

...also make sure you're saving the docs to a fast (local) drive and not some slower network location.

You might also be interested in the Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files and Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files topics in the Mailmerge Tips and Tricks page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. The second of these allows you to run the mailmerge directly from Excel. For your purposes, simply comment-out the first .SaveAs line in each macro.
